# Как дождаться окончания вывода в в stdin в rust

Tags: rust

Есть такая программа-пример на Rust:

```
use indicatif::*;
use std::{sync::mpsc, sync::mpsc::*, thread};

pub enum Output {
    Finish,
    Tick,
}

fn main() {
    let (tx, rx) = mpsc::channel::<Output>();

    let join_handle = thread::spawn(move || {
        handle_output_messages(70_000, rx);
    });

    (0..70_000).for_each(|_| tx.send(Output::Tick).unwrap()); // Тут 70 000 раз обновили прогресс-бар

    tx.send(Output::Finish).unwrap(); // Тут например показали результат

    join_handle.join().unwrap();
}

pub fn handle_output_messages(total_things: u64, rx: Receiver<Output>) {
    let multi_bar = MultiProgress::new();
    let progress_bar = multi_bar.add(ProgressBar::new(total_things));

    thread::spawn(move || {
        for output in rx {
            match output {
                Output::Tick => progress_bar.inc(1),
                Output::Finish => {
                    progress_bar.finish();
                    (0..600).for_each(|x| println!("{:?}", x));
                }
            }
        }
    });

    multi_bar.join_and_clear().unwrap();
}
```

Часть результирующего вывода

```
...
588
████████████████████░░░░░░░░░░ 54620/70000
590
████████████████████░░░░░░░░░░ 54621/70000
592
████████████████████░░░░░░░░░░ 54622/70000
████████████████████░░░░░░░░░░ 54623/70000
595
████████████████████░░░░░░░░░░ 54624/70000
597
598
```

Собственно моя проблема в том, что у меня начинает перемешивать вывод прогресс-бара с выводом того текста, который должен быть показан после прогресс-бара.

Какие есть идеи, как правильно дожидаться того момента, когда прогресс-бар закончит себя рисовать?

Comment: Может использовать в коде `print!` и `io::stdout().flush()`?

Answer (score 1):

В итоге стал выводить все данные после прогресс-бара через

```
progress_bar.println(msg);
```

https://docs.rs/indicatif/0.11.0/indicatif/struct.ProgressBar.html#method.println

И всё встало на свои места.